# Notify client application from wcf service

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc, wcf, signalr

I have a wpf application which is running on diffrunt clients pc which get data from a wcf web service.

Now when update some data from web service I need to notify that to perticar client.

So I need to push data from web service to client

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use Duplex service in WCF

[Sample Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by those above, a duplex service in WCF would work for you. There are alternatives though that achieve a similar function, but may not fulfill your needs.

[SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

[WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx)

and server polling (you can google this for many various articles explaining it).

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the Observer design pattern.

For my surprise, Wikipedia gives a very good definition on the first paragraph about this pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Hope this works for you.